# Conditional Formatting Using Variable Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I'm building a spreadsheet to use at the family health unit where I work. I have a spreadsheet where column G indicates the patient's gender, and column O indicates the patient's waist circumference value. I would like the cells in column O to turn red if the value were > 80 for women and > 102 for men, according to the data in column G.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=((G2="male")*(O2>102))+((G2="female")*(O2>80))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to do this formatting with the tip you gave me. I loved! Thank you very much! I apologize for the delay in responding here.